# incorporating loop into file processing

Tags: loops, awk, sed

I have several line of code that looks something like this, although it is able to only process one file (*5cym24.pdb*), *i.e.*:

```
grep -E 'TRP' 5cym24.pdb > 5cym24_d.pdb
grep -E 'CYS' 5cym24.pdb > 5cym24_b.pdb
sed -n '3030,3106p;3138,3205p;3238,3268p;3329,3361p;3423,3453p' 5cym24.pdb > 5cym24_a.pdb
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS=, 5cym24_d.pdb > 5cym24_d.csv
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS=, 5cym24_b.pdb > 5cym24_b.csv
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS=, 5cym24_a.pdb > 5cym24_a.csv
```

My question is, how do I include a loop such that it processes the many *pdb* files that I have, *i.e.*, *5cymX.pdb*, where *X* ranges from 24 to 70, for example, thus generating *5cymX_d.pdb*, *5cymX_b.pdb*, *5cymX_a.pdb*, *5cymX_d.csv*, *5cymX_b.csv*, *5cymX_a.csv*. Thanks!

Comment: Not clear, please do add more information to your post and let us know then.

Comment: You don't. Everything you're doing and everything you want to do can almost certainly be done with just 1 call to awk. [edit] your question to show a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output to get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

do_work() {
    grep -E 'TRP' "5cym$1.pdb" > "5cym$1_d.pdb"
    grep -E 'CYS' "5cym$1.pdb" > "5cym$1_b.pdb"
    sed -n '3030,3106p;3138,3205p;3238,3268p;3329,3361p;3423,3453p' "5cym$1.pdb" > "5cym$1_a.pdb"
    awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS=, "5cym$1_d.pdb" > "5cym$1_d.csv"
    awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS=, "5cym$1_b.pdb" > "5cym$1_b.csv"
    awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS=, "5cym$1_a.pdb" > "5cym$1_a.csv"
}

for i in $(seq 24 70); do
   do_work "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your existing code:

```
grep -E 'TRP' 5cym24.pdb > 5cym24_d.pdb
grep -E 'CYS' 5cym24.pdb > 5cym24_b.pdb
sed -n '3030,3106p;3138,3205p;3238,3268p;3329,3361p;3423,3453p' 5cym24.pdb > 5cym24_a.pdb
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS=, 5cym24_d.pdb > 5cym24_d.csv
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS=, 5cym24_b.pdb > 5cym24_b.csv
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS=, 5cym24_a.pdb > 5cym24_a.csv
```

can be reduced to just 1 call to awk (untested of course since you didn't provide sample input/output to test against):

```
awk -v OFS=',' '
    FNR==1 {
        close(base"_a.csv")
        close(base"_b.csv")
        close(base"_d.csv")
        base = FILENAME
        sub(/\.pdb$/,"",base)
    }
    { $1=$1 }
    /TRP/ { print > (base"_d.csv") }
    /CYS/ { print > (base"_b.csv") }
    (FNR>=3030 && FNR<=3106) || (FNR>=3138 && FNR<=3205) || (FNR>=3238 && FNR<=3268) ||
    (FNR>=3329 && FNR<=3361) || (FNR>=3423 && FNR<=3453) { print > (base"_a.csv") }
' 5cym24.pdb
```

and you could probably just change `5cym24.pdb` to `*.pdb` (or whatever list of input files you want to provide) and it'd simply work as-is for all of your files at once.